# get everything after last character occurrence python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've seen this asked in other languages but can't find it for Python, maybe it has a specific name i'm not aware of. I want to split a line after the last occurrence of a '-' character, my string would look like the following:

```
POS--K    100    100    001    -    1462
```

I want to take the last number from this string after the last -, in this case 1462. I have no idea how to achieve this in, to achieve this when only one such character is expected I would use the following:

```
last_number = last_number[last_number.index('-')+1:]
```

How would I achieve this when an unknown number of - could be present and the end number could be of any length?

Comment: or `str.rpartition()`...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You were almost there. `index` selects from the left, and `rindex` selects from the right:

```
>>> s = 'POS--K    100    100    001    -    1462'
>>> s[s.rindex('-')+1:]
'    1462'
```

Comment: well that was incredibly simple as most things are in Python :) perfect thank you

Comment: Note - this method will raise 'ValueError: substring not found' if '-' was not found. The alternative answer from @BhargavRao instead returns the whole string if '-' was not found.

Answer (score 23):

You can do this if you want the last number after the last `-`

```
>>> s = "POS--K    100    100    001    -    1462"
>>> a = s.split('-')[-1]
>>> a
'    1462'
>>> a.strip()
'1462'
```

Or as Padraic mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942128/get-everything-after-last-character-occurrence-python/27942164?noredirect=1#comment44281754_27942164), you can use `rsplit`

```
>>> s = "POS--K    100    100    001    -    1462"
>>> a = s.rsplit('-',1)[1]
>>> a
'    1462'
>>> a.strip()
'1462'
```

The rsplit solution, however, will not work if there is no occurrence of the character, since then there will be only one element in the array returned.

Comment: `s.rsplit('-',1)[1]` will be a little more efficient